# Estimate integral

Tags: calculus

can you please answer the below problem:
Let $n$ be an arbitrary positive integer. If the substitution $u=1+x^{1/n}$ is made in the integral

> $$\int\sqrt{1+x^{1/n}}\space dx.$$

What is the new integral?

I reach:

$u=1+x^{1/n}$, from that $x=(u-1)^n$, Then $dx=n(u-1)^{n-1}du$. Thus, $\int u^{1/2} n(u-1)^{n-1} du$

However, I couldn't go further due to the final expression is still can't be integral. So can you please help me.
Thank you,

Comment: Re-write the math expressions in a TeX format

Comment: Depending on the source, maybe the question is just asking you to carry out the substitution, so that the "answer" is the transformed integral you already have in the post. "What is the new integral" is a bit different from "what is the *value* of the new integral", at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion

$x^{\frac{1}{n}}=\sinh^2(u)$

so $\sqrt{1+x^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(u)}=\sqrt{cosh^2(u)}= \cosh(u)$

and $dx=(2n \sinh^{2n-1}(u) * (\cosh (u ))\ du$

Comment: where did you came with (sinh u)^2, there is no such sin or cos in the mentioned problem

Comment: because it will be easier to solve .after that you can return to u or x

Answer (score 0):

Expand $(u-1)^{n-1}$ using binomial theorem and integrate.

Comment: how can i do that